# Cannot Enable Cloud Datastore API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I cannot enable Google Cloud Datastore API in the cloud console.  It's showing a dialog that states:

> Cannot ENABLE any API when there is a pending request to DISABLE any API

How to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a temporary issue and should be resolved now.